# Is anyone aware of a LIDAR solution including a horizontal angular sweep of >10 degrees and up to 10-20 meters of range?

Tags: lidar

Is anyone aware of a LIDAR solution including a horizontal angular sweep of >10 degrees and up to 10-20 meters of range?  I've looked but can't seem to find the just right solution.  Anyone who has made a comprehensive tabulated list of current LIDAR offerings out there?

Comment: Hi Ted, thank you for your post. Unfortunately, product recommendations are off-topic here since they typically become obsolete quickly, while discussions of engineering theory and practice can remain useful in the long-term.

Comment: I have never seen a scanning LIDAR that does not meet these specs.

Comment: TFmini Infrared Module Specification (0.3m-12m):
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/102375/controlling-5-lidars-using-raspberry-pi

Comment: I assume "*just right solution*" means cheap because scanning LIDARs are not cheap and they all scan far larger than 10 deg since there is zero extra effort to do so after you have the mirror assembly.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, nanofarad.  I probably should have been more concise, DKNguyen.  I'm not really looking for a scanning variety.  As you guessed, I'm more interested in a cheaper approach using a lense to distribute the beam across a modest angular range, to catch the presence of an obstacle more or less in front of the emitter but tolerant of a little off-axis.  I don't much care about the small trigonometric inaccuracies.  Can one just put a lense in front of any old LIDER emitter/receiver?  The range is the greater consideration.  I'll study your suggestion tlfong01.  Thanks all.

Comment: Oh, so you're not searching for a 10 degree angular sweep, but a 10 degree field of view. (although I guess field of view could also be used for scanning LIDARs). When I saw sweep I assumed scanning because scanning LIDARs actually sweep the beam.

Answer (score 1):

Luminar should have the technology for that, but I'm not sure their products are even publically available anymore. I think an automobile consortium grabbed Luminar, to keep their products/technology away from the competition.

You can search for Luminar and its competitors, perhaps at self-drive conferences a few years ago.

Luminar was using arrays of photodiodes, and/or arrays of lasers, to up the scan rate and also increase the lateral pixel density.

===================================

Sounds like you want to have a BAR OF LIGHT, and have a photodetector respond to reflected photons.

Comment: Thanks, analogsystemsrf.  I'm looking over the Luminar offerings.  They seem to still be in business (luminartech.com).  I earlier bought a pricey Leddar Sensor Evaluation Kit from Leddartech in Quebec, which incorporated about 16 dedicated emitters covering about 90 degrees of angular range, I believe.  But communication with it was ModBus based and beyond its demo program, I couldn't find a way to get the ModBus working with it.

Comment: STMicroelectronics is offering some of the lowest cost solutions and cheap demo boards, but their range is still rather short.